When solving second order linear differential equation...
Lots of people assume $y = e^{\lambda x}$ when solving the differential equation $y'' + ay' + b = 0$.
What if there is a solution that is not of the form $e^{\lambda x}$?
Can we prove that the solution is a linear combination of the form $y = e^{\lambda x}$?
